# What is the max_fd number of dup2() function?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

```
int main()
{
    int err1, err2;
    struct rlimit rlim;

    err = getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &rlim);
    printf("max_fds: %d\n", rlim.rlim_max); // 4096

    err1 = dup2(1, 1023);  // OK
    err2 = dup2(2, 4090);  // error: EBADF

    return 0;
}
```

Like the codes above, I use getrlimit to get the max# of open files per process and it prints 4096. However, when I deliver the newfd which is bigger than 1023 to dup2(), it always return error EBADF.  Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getrlimit()` returns a structure `rlimit` that contains two values:

- the **current** limit, called `rlim_cur`, which is the value that the kernel enforces for the corresponding resource.
- the **maximum** limit, called `rlim_max`, which is the ceiling value that an unpriviliged user can set `rlim_cur` to.

tl;dr, use `rlim_cur`!

```
printf("max_fds: %d\n", rlim.rlim_cur); // probably 1024 by default on most distribs
```

Answer (score 1):

Does your platform have `getdtablesize()` available?  If so, that's the place to look.  That may be the real limit on fd's for you.

Comment: Yes, it's available and shows 1024, make the program right :)